# Is domain verification is necessary for Facebook server side conversion pixel API?

Tags: facebook, pixel, server-side

In Facebook conversion API doc it is written that domain verification is needed to upload data to Facebook but while integrating the server side conversion API I was able to load pixel data successfully to my Facebook business account from my application without verifying my domain.

Hence I want to confirm is it necessary to verify domain or not for successful integration of Facebook server side conversion API.

Kindly acknowledge my query and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Please link to the exact part of the documentation that you are referring to.

Comment: I believe it is not, but does not harm you to do it.